# to align rows fetched from shell script output

Tags: shell

The output from the shell scripts is like :

```
343434345,5454645645645,ACTIVE,2011-05-25 14:34;refid=134053  
90092;pep.state=ACTIVATED  
343434345,5454645645645,ACTIVE,2011-05-25 14:34;refid=134053     
90092;pep.state=ACTIVATED
```

And it gets pasted in the editplus in identical manner.

But I want my output to be in complete line instead of two lines. Like :

```
343434345,5454645645645,ACTIVE,2011-05-25 14:34;refid=13405390092;pep.state=ACTIVATED
343434345,5454645645645,ACTIVE,2011-05-25 14:34;refid=13405390092;pep.state=ACTIVATED
```

P.S. Data been fetched from database.

How can that be possible ? Pls advise !

Comment: please post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the shell script

Comment: sqlplus -s usname/passwd@IPXDB  > /home/ACTIVATE << EOF
set echo on
set pagesize 0
set verify off
set lines 32000
set trimspool on
set feedback off
select column1,coulmn2
from table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
Where
t1.id = '3110'
And t1.attr like '%IRCTC%';
exit;
EOF

Comment: Pls if anyone can help it is urgent !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(g)awk` to the rescue:

```
awk 'NR % 2 == 1 { saved_line=$0 ; next } { print saved_line $0 }' INPUTFILE
```

will do.

It will save every odd lines to a variable, then prints it and the next line. *Note*: it can be done more than one way, e.g. this does the same:

awk '{printf("%s",$0) ; getline ; printf("%s\n",$0)} INPUTFILE

HTH